# Programming language to do pivot table drag and drop

Tags: c#, php

does php or java able to do the drag and drop pivot table just like the c# winform devexpress? please advise.TQ

Comment: Not related to a particular programming language, only to implementation of some UI control - and yes, there are similar controls for Java (Swing, Web) and PHP (Web).

Comment: Not sure why people are so quick to downvote questions here and put them on hold. This question wasn't unclear at all.

Comment: Not sure why. @KevinAdams mybe they are all expert. =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not natively but I believe there are 3rd party controls available. I don't remember them being nearly as full featured as DevExpress, but it's been a few years since I've looked around.